# how can I get overflow scroll bars to be hidden unless needed when using jquery ui's resizable?

Tags: jquery, html, css, angularjs, jquery-ui

Live sample: http://plnkr.co/edit/ivjvAZ?p=preview

I'm using jquery ui and angular to make a resizable directive for divs that are absolutely positioned.

The problem here is that the divs have scrollbars all of the time, even the mostly empty ones. I want the blue box to be resizable but not to have scroll bars when all the content is visible. I need the green box divs to be resizable and draggable, so the absolute positioning has to stay (doesn't it?).

How can I get these scrollbars to only show when needed?

[image: screenshot of the unwanted scrollbars]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add this to your css:

```
.ng-scope .ui-resizable-e {
    right: 0px;
}

.ng-scope .ui-resizable-s {
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

The `.ng-scope` part is to add specificity and also higher priority for the defined styles to the selected elements in your markup.

**DEMO:** http://plnkr.co/edit/IXicY5sjAI6CJVWUqFFU?p=preview

**Explanation:** The container `div` has `overflow: auto;` and the scroll handles have a width and height of 100% and a position of `bottom: -5px;` and `right: -5px;` (100% of the container and offset of some pixels on each direction) which always automatically push them out of the viewable part of their container, so the scrollbars always show up because of the `overflow: auto;` property.

Comment: Bam, that did it. Can you help me and tell me why that works?

Comment: Great job @Arbel, I was fixing the issue in [another way](http://plnkr.co/edit/1KizgWYxhkT6Kp9U51oi?p=preview).

Comment: @HashemQolami thanks, certainly there could be other approaches that address the main cause.

Answer (score -1):

Set overflow to 'auto'

```
overflow:auto;
```

Comment: Nope, I didn't realise the link was your code as it wasn't mentioned and you never informed us what you had tried.

Comment: It's the first line of my question.

Comment: Before you edited, it was just a link which could have been linking anywhere.

Comment: Plnkr is a code sharing site like jsfiddle. The More You Know.

Comment: Thanks, that'll help avoid this in the future :)

Comment: Dude, I can see that you downvoted my question. Was that really necessary? It looks like a retributive downvote. If you think it's missing something you should add a comment.